# Should I keep Application subclass object as a member or local variable?

Tags: java, member, local-variables, android

I was wondering, I am using Application subclass to access some global data inside Activities. And I was wondering what would be better in terms off performance and memory.

Is it better to assign application object to field variable in onCreate and access it as a mamber

```
Activity

 onCreate() {
     mApp = (MyApplication) getApplication()
 }
```

or

Dont use a member and call getApplication every single time and assign it just to a local variable?

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication()
```

From my knowledge, local variables are allowed to be garbage collected right away but members have to be kept in memory.

Since I presume Application object is a big object, is it okay to keep it in memory or should I allow it to get garbage collected?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application` object would always be in memory. It's only its reference that you are either caching as a field member or retrieving it every time for a local variable. The latter doesn't give you any space or time benefits.

---

The `Application` object along with all of its children and grandchildren objects would live on *`heap`* only. All that the method `getApplication()` is doing is to return the *`address`* to the *`root`* of this object tree. The address/pointer/reference size would remain the same irrespective of how long the object tree or big each object element is.

Comment: Cool, thanks!
Now lets imagine some different custom big pojo object, would my assumptions be correct then?

Comment: The big `Object` along with all of its children and grandchildren would live on `heap` only. All that the method `getApplication()` is doing is to return the *address* of the *root* of this tree. The address/reference size would remain the same irrespective of how long/big the tree or each element is.